# I want to align a logo at the center of the screen and display few lines right after the image.But the text is coinciding with the image

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML code:

```
<img class="centeredimage"  src="BLACK.jpg"><br><br>
        <p align="center" class="new"><b><span class="main_text">This is regarding....</span></b><br><br>
        <span class = "a2017">Welcome to 2017</span><br><br>
        <span class="coming_soon">Coming Soon</span></p><br><br>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
.centeredimage {
     position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
        }
.new{
        color:#FFFFFF;
        }

.main_text{
        font-size:20px;
        letter-spacing: 8px;
        }
.a2017{
          font-size:15px ;
          letter-spacing:2px ;
        }
.coming_soon{
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        }
```

The image is aligned at center of the screen but the text instead of getting displayed after the image is displayed coinciding with the image.How do I make it come after the image so that both are aligned at middle of the screen at center?

Comment: What do you mean by "after". Do you mean "under", or "to the right of"?

Comment: I mean after in the next  line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.centeredimage {
 display : block;
 width: 200px;
margin: auto;
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to center things in the middle of the screen, for example, a loader. It can have multiple parts, it doesn't matter. You just put all the parts into one div. I used to use the "margin" trick, and still do here and there, but these days I'm using the table/tablecell thing to get the job done. It works everywhere, phones etc. (note I don't deal with 10-year-old browsers). Below is some code straight from an instructional sample:

```
<style>
        .app_style {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: table;
        }
        .loader_style {
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .loader_icon_style {
            border: 2px solid lightgray;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        }
        .loader_bar_padding {
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
        .loader_blurb {
            width: inherit;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: yellow;
            font-style: italic;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <sample-app class="app_style">
        <div class="loader_style">
            <img class="loader_icon_style" src="assets/images/r2-d2.jpg" />
            <div class="loader_blurb loader_bar_padding">
                May the force be with you...
            </div>
            <img class="loader_bar_padding" src="assets/images/loader-bar.gif" />
        </div>
    </sample-app>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want center the image and the text, not align only the image otherwise the text follow an other logic on the DOM, mostly if you use the absolute position for the image and not for the text.

You can use a wrapper div aligned to the center and put all content in it.

```css
body {
background-color:#ff00ff;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}


.your_image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.new {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.main_text {
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
}

.a2017 {
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.coming_soon {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <img class="your_image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/1122px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png"><br><br>
  <p align="center" class="new"><b><span class="main_text">This is regarding....</span></b><br><br>
    <span class="a2017">Welcome to 2017</span><br><br>
    <span class="coming_soon">Coming Soon</span></p><br><br>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works! But when the text is long it expands over more than one line.It should be in one line.How to solve that? If I am using margin-left text's some part is hidden in mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use Flexbox. It simplifies a lot of the coding you need to do.

In your situation, just wrap your HTMl code in a div and make this your CSS:

```
div{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.centeredimage {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
        }
```